# Ring of congruence classes $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is the same as the quotient ring $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: ring-theory

The ring operations are exactly the same and the elements are exactly the same, so does the slightly different way they are constructed matter?

Comment: What is that "slightly different" way they're constructed? One is just a short form of writing the other one.

Comment: What does the congruence relation mean? It means to take $n$ to be $0$, i.e. to form the quotient ring. So the two constructions coincide in fact.

Comment: Well I guess what I want to ask then is are they the same because there is an obvious isomorphism or are they literally the same thing?

Comment: "The elements are the same and the operations are the same" is the definition of ring isomorphism...

Answer (score 1):

Both $\mathbb{Z}_n$ and $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ should be interpreted as meaning exactly the same thing.  The distinction is only at the level of notation.

They are not just isomorphic rings, but are, in fact, equal.